# Is file-input thread-safe in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, file

In Python2, is it safe to have multiple threads read from a single unchanging disk file using code such as:

```
with open( pathname, 'rb' ) as f:
    f.seek( file_position )
    data = f.read( number_of_bytes )
```

No process has, or will have, write-permission for the file.

Obviously, reading files in this way is not atomic.  The Python2 documents say nothing (I could find) about file objects and threads.  Here is the documentation for the `seek` method:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file-objects

This is a critical issue for my system, so if pointers into the documentation could be provided, that would be reassuring.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each thread executes the code you've given, they open the file separately, and this is safe.  I'm not sure to what documentation to refer you; this is just a result of a process being allowed to have the same file open more than once.  You may not be on a POSIX system, but for reference it describes an [open file description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) as the thing created by `open()` (in C, but wrapped by Python) that holds the file offset and other information relevant to accessing the file.

Comment: Thank you.  Your last sentence is key because it says that Python file objects are independent from each other even when they exist in a many-to-one relationship with the file-that-is-on-the-disk.